# hostname and localhost not redirecting to sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, redirect

I have a sharepoint site running with custom master page. To access the site I to write complete url i.e.: http://servername/sites/sitename/pages/page.aspx

Ideally we should able to access the site with only hostname or by localhost, but in this environment I am not able to access like this !!

any one have resolution or reason of it  !!

Comment: set welcome page to page which u want to redirect after typing by hostname only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Publishing site (or site with publishing feature enabled), you can simply use the old “Welcome Page” link in the Site settings to set the URL of a page this is the desired home page for your SharePoint site.

[image]

[See Reference](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/09/05/how-to-set-a-page-as-home-page-in-sharepoint-2013-site/)

Now if try opening ur site only with host name it will redirect to ur default page.

**Note:** Whenever u delete that page u have to first remove that page from welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your host name to the Alternate access mapping? I saw a similar problem at customer site and they'd typed the alternate access mapping address incorrectly.